# Read first x lines of csv file into new outfile?

Tags: shell, csv, terminal

How would one copy only the first x lines of a `csv` file into a new `csv` file via the terminal?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: `head -N file.csv > newfile.csv`

Answer (score 90):

## Brief

(You'll use a linux terminal/console)

Use `head -n NUMBEROFLINES file.csv` to get the first `NUMBEROFLINES` of lines. Write it into another file using shell redirection (`>`) like this:

```
head -n NUMBEROFLINES file.csv > mynewfile.csv
```

Note that this will totally recreate `mynewfile.csv`, **if it had any content before it is now deleted forever**(-ish).

If you ever happen to want the opposite (**last** x lines), use `tail`.

Both tools come with man and info pages (`man head` or `info head` - get used to `man`, though) and a `--help` flag (`head --help` actually shows me more or less the man page).

#### Full example

```
head -n 10 data.csv >> /tmp/first_and_last.csv # Note the ">>"
tail -n 10 data.csv >> /tmp/first_and_last.csv # Note the ">>"
```

This would open the file `/tmp/first_and_last.csv` and attach (`>>`, `>` would recreate/delete the file!) the first and the last 10 lines of `data.csv` at the "end" of `/tmp/first_and_last.csv`.

**Mac OS X:**
According to the internet (tm) these commands are available in (Unix-based) Mac OS as well (you have to start the Terminal via Finder).

**More speaking examples**

`-n` is short for `--lines=`, so you could also use:

```
tail --lines=10 data.csv >> addtothisfile.txt
head --lines=10 data.csv >> addtothisfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for you if your CSV contains "lines" containing newline seperators, e.g. in Quotes. A short PHP Script that would solve this issue, so you would get 1500 "lines"/"datasets", each possibly containing multiple "file lines"

```
<?php
$input = fopen($argv[1], "r");
$output = fopen($argv[2], "w+");

$limit = $argv[3];
$counter = 0;
while($counter <= $limit) {
    echo $counter;
    $line = fgetcsv($input);
    fputcsv($output, $line);
    $counter++;
}
```

To execute:

```
php -f scriptname.php input.csv output.csv 1500
```